# UIActivityIndicator is showing behind everything else in my view

Tags: swift, ios8, spinner, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to get my UIActivityIndicator to show on top of everything. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to do so. It shows up like so (actual spinner is on top, but background is behind everything):

[image]

It shows behind everything in the view. Here is my code:

```
var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150))
self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
self.activityIndicator.backgroundColor = (UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.8))
self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
self.activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 5
view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

How can I make my activityIndicator background to show up on top of everything (as the spinner is doing so)?

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: Actually you're wrong. The spinner is _not_ somehow is separated from its background. That would be impossible. They are together. The spinner is _not_ in front of everything. The P in Password is in front of the spinner. The white surrounding Log In is in front of the spinner. Now you have to ask yourself - how did they get there? Use the View Debugger to examine the views and layering and see.

Comment: Did you try the `.layer.zPosition` property?

Comment: use MBProgressHUD and if you dont use CocoaPods then just get the two files and put them into your swift project and update  ur bridging header file

Comment: how do I use the `.layer.zPosition` property? I have never used it before...

Comment: @matt sorry I am kind of new to Xcode, could you elaborate on your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding `self.activityIndicator` to the view hierarchy, you could call `view.bringSubviewToFront(self.activityIndicator)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the process of adding a background color to your `UIActivityIndicatorView`, but it's a stop-gap solution in my opinion.

Instead, I would strongly recommend using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

It's open source, easy to drop in (includes CocoaPods support), and is incredibly easy to use. It's a much nicer user experience than dealing with your own background colors, fading/animation, rounded corners, etc. and smooshing it on top of everything else in your view stack.

Comment: I looked at the library and it seems pretty easy to use. I was wondering if you could help me out by providing an example in Swift (because all examples are in Obj-C and I have never really used it, apart from the bridging headers). Thank you for your help!